# Do indexes remain after a join?

Tags: database, indexing, database-indexes

Given the relations below:

```
create table Students (
sid     integer,     -- 4 bytes
name    varchar(30), -- average length 20 bytes (incl padding)
bday    date,        -- 4 bytes
degree  char(4),     -- 4 bytes
primary key (id)
);

create table Courses (
cid     integer,     -- 4 bytes
code    char(8),     -- 8 bytes
term    char(4),     -- 4 bytes
title   varchar(40), -- average length 24 bytes (incl padding)
primary key (cid)
);

create table Enrolments (
course  integer,     -- 4 bytes
student integer,     -- 4 bytes
mark    integer,     -- 4 bytes
grade   char(2),     -- 4 bytes (with padding)
foreign key (course) references Courses(cid),
foreign key (student) references Students(sid)
);
```

The primary keys `cid` and `sid` each have a two-level B-tree index.

If I were to initially join `Courses` and `Enrolments` and THEN join this result to `Students`, would it be possible for the final table result to still have two indexes on `cid` and `sid`?

If someone could please explain the mechanics of this, I wouyld greatly appreciate it!

Comment: ...eh? "final table result"? Does not parse: The result of a join isn't a newly created table. This question seems to be based on a false premise.

Comment: ...if you're asking if the indexes on the source tables can be used in performing a query against a subselect (or similar) represented by the join, that's an entirely different question (and the answer is often yes).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What I meant was, assuming that I had stored the result of the JOINS, would it be possible to use the two indexes if I were to run a query against this result?

Comment: If you "stored" the result of the joins that would be in a new table and that table would not have the index in it. However Internally it doesn't work that way. If you looked at the query plan, its entirely possibly that the join occurs directly between the indexes (not actual table rows), and subsequent operations (filters etc.) are effectively run only against the indexes. Basically it does not work the way you think it does. If you are using SQL Server, press CTRL-L to see the query plan and you'll get an idea. Databases create optimisation objects on the fly (statistics, spooling, tempdb)

Comment: If inserting the results of a query into a new table created indexes in that new table, that would come with a nontrivial cost: You'd need to store the indexes, and even more importantly, you'd need to **update** the indexes whenever the data in that new table changed. (Because of this being a new table proper, as opposed to a materialized view, it could be updated independently of the source content -- or the source content updated independent of it -- so the original indexes couldn't be used for queries against that new table).

Comment: Because persisted indexes have costs -- sometimes, heavy costs -- creating them without explicit user approval would be extremely bad form.